# Mount --bind versus symlinks

Tags: mount, symbolic-link, symlink

Linux server
`/www/website` directory is my html directory
Want users to ftp to `/user/website/public_html` directory which is chrooted and limited to ftp only access

I currently accomplish this via
 `sudo mount --bind /www/website /user/website/public_html -t ext4`.
However, this breaks and stops working after a few days (not sure why).

So should I be using mount --bind OR should I be using symlinks?  If mount --bind, how can I prevent it from breaking?

Comment: it is not necessary to use "-t ext4"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your system periodically reboot?  If you are doing bind mounts you really should be setting them up in your `/etc/fstab`.  You should only be manually mounting them if they are meant to be temporary.  There is no magic that automatically restores mounts after a reboot.  You need to configure your system to mount things.

Bind mounts look like below in your fstab.

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vg1-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# also mount root to /srv/vg1-root/
/               /srv/vg1-root/  none    bind
```

Comment: Thanks.  I assume the reboot is breaking the mount.  I will try the fstab.